# Printing numbers and text into a canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to print a variable, which is a number, together with text into a canvas with the Tkinter module in Python. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. This is the code that I currently have for it:

```
from tkinter import  *
from random import *

def Spelmenu():
    global punt1
    global punt2
    global punt3

    spelmenu = Tk()
    spelmenu.geometry('600x600')
    spelmenu.title('Spelen maar!')
    spelmenu.configure(background='darkgrey')
    spelmenu.minsize(600, 600)
    spelmenu.maxsize(600, 600)
    volgendeB = Button(spelmenu, text='Volgende beurt!', bd='5', height='2', width='15')
    volgendeB.place(x=240, y=550)

    Naam1="Jack"
    wBeurt = Canvas(spelmenu, width=500, height=60)
    wBeurt.place(x=50, y=70)
    wBeurt.create_text(250, 30, text=Naam1 + " is aan de beurt!")

    scores = Canvas(spelmenu, width=500, height=300)
    scores.place(x=50, y=160)
    worp1=randint(1,6)
    worp2=randint(1,6)
    fWorp1=str(worp1)
    fWorp2=str(worp2)

    if worp1 < worp2 or worp1 > worp2:
        punt1=2
        scores.create_text(text="Je hebt "+ fWorp1+ "en "+ fWorp2+ "gegooit dus je hebt 2 punten gekregen!")
    else:
        punt1=5
        scores.create_text(text="Je hebt "+ fWorp1+ "en "+ fWorp2+ "gegooit dus je hebt 5 punten gekregen!")

    mainloop()

Spelmenu()
```

It leaves me with this error

```
  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `fWorp1=str(worp1)` and `fWorp2=str(worp2)`

Comment: This does solve one of the problems. It now gives me an error in the scores.create_text line. This is the error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Did you use the above code? The above code will definitely both the problems.

Comment: Yes, I used the code you send, but it still gives me an error when I try to put the variable with normal text.

Comment: Why are you using `fWorp1=worp1.get()` ? What do you expect to get from it.

Comment: Update your question with the code changes.  Also you need to provide `(x, y)` when calling `.create_text()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I saw someone use it in a video that I looked up about the topic but i probably didn't use it correctly. I have changed it to a str() which does work

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you so much for reminding me of that. I added it and now it works well :)

Comment: @Beaver `get()` is only for widgets, not text or int